# How can I transfer DevOps data to any BI tool?

Tags: azure-devops

I have data on Azure DevOps which gets updated every 5 minutes. Using this data I want to create a dashboard in some BI tool which will provide a consolidated view of the data. I am currently using MicroStrategy which does not support DevOps. Using Power Bi is not an option. 
I want an indirect way through which I can pull the data in DevOps into MicroStrategy maybe through Azure Cosmos DB. So can I transfer data in devops to cosmos db??

Comment: Which data you need? Maybe there are covered by the [Azure Devops REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Comment: Can I transfer data from DevOps to cosmos Db? Forgive me if I sound silly, I'm new at this

Comment: I don't know `Cosmos DB` but if `Cosmos DB` has an API to receive data, of cause you can do that.

Comment: @Rithwik Sarma how is going with this case? Is below answer of any help to you?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I'm currently trying to work on it. Was occupied with something else

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple application to get the data from Devops with  Azure Devops REST API [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and using Azure Cosmos DB API [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction) to store these data in Cosmos DB.

This is sample project provided by Microsoft, introducing how to store and access data from an ASP.NET MVC application hosted on Azure Websites using Azure Cosmos DB service
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/documentdb-dotnet-todo-app

You can check the tutorial provided by Microsoft 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/cosmos-db?view=azure-devops